# Exception throwing on button click in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have my interface like.

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HistoryShow : UIViewController {

}

 -(IBAction) listTableViewController:(id) sender;  

@end
```

and my implementation file is like below.

```
-(IBAction) listTableViewController:(id) sender {

    NSLog(@"Loaded");

    NSLog(@"FFFFFFFFFFF");

    //MyViewController *vewq = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //[self.view addSubview:vewq.view]; 
    //[vewq release];

}
```

My problem is that when i am clicking on RectButton from my interface i am getting an error message on my console windows.Which is.

> [__NSCFType listTableViewController:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4b2fb40 2011-06-01 18:33:09.432
>   TableView[3067:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFType
>   listTableViewController:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4b2fb40'

What is the exact problem?

Comment: Check your interface builder xib file..have you connected all the methods and outlets correctly?

Comment: Yes. I connected to the function from Builder and this is showing there also. Any other place to chek it ?

Comment: It is showing Touch Up Inside --> File's Owner listTableViewController

Comment: this exception generally raises because of interface builder connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check in your XIB file...

and set all IBOutlets properly.....

drag button's touchupInside to FilesOwner and select your method....

there is no any problem in your code......

Answer (score 0):

Check by using the below code

```
-(IBAction) listTableViewController
{
 NSLog(@"Loaded");

NSLog(@"FFFFFFFFFFF");

//MyViewController *vewq = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];

//[self.view addSubview:vewq.view]; 
//[vewq release];

}
```

you need to use **@selector(listTableViewController:)** when you assign the method to UIButton and also change the function prototype to    **-(IBAction) listTableViewController:(id) sender**